# Feeding Spacy NER model negative examples to improve training

Tags: python, spacy

I've fed spacy's ner model a set of GoldParse objects to train on.

What I'd like to do now is evaluate its results on new sentences and mark each recognized entity as 'good' or 'bad', then incorporate this information in a new batch of training.

Is this possible?  How can the ner model learn from negative samples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to learn from the negative examples -- it's implemented in spaCy because it's a key feature of our commercial annotation tool, Prodigy: https://prodi.gy

To mark a span as "not PERSON", you can makes its label !PERSON. That should be all you need to do. There's currently no easy way to encode constraints like "not PERSON and not ORG" -- you would have to customise the cost functions, within `spacy/syntax/ner.pyx`

The model can learn from annotations like "not PERSON" because spaCy's NER and parser both use transition-based imitation learning algorithms. At each word we're trying to predict which action to take, to transform the current state. The supervision comes from an oracle that tells us which actions will introduce new errors. If we know that some span of text isn't a person, the oracle can use that to mark some of the actions as costly. We'll have multiple zero-cost actions, but that's normal --- it happens a lot in the normal training anyway.

You can learn more about how the entity recogniser works in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqDHBH9IjRU